# Class conflict while integrating CakePHP with phpBB

Tags: php, cakephp, conflict, forum, phpbb

I have an existing web application that I'm trying to add a forum to - the forum of choice being phpBB. I'm trying to bridge the two, so that users and sessions are used across both my application and the forum.

Unfortunately, phpBB contains a 'User' class that comes into conflict with the User class that I already have implemented in my site extensively ("Cannot redeclare class User.." blablabla).

I have tried some things myself with no success, and saw a suggestion to use namespaces, which aren't supported in CakePHP yet.

Is there any way around renaming my User class? Has anyone else had a similar issue, and had success with a different forum software?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you why you are merging two frameworks? Can't you solve it on the database or client (js) level?

Comment: The ideal solution is to use namespaces to resolve this. That will only work in the software you're using is written to support namespaces. I think Cake is, but not sure about phpBB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a clear cut solution, but more a line of thought:
How about loading the phpBB class aliased?
[`ClassRegistry::init()`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/class-registry) allows you to load a Class and assign an alias to it.